# VS Code Decoration API - Hide original text

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I have been digging into VS Code's Extension APIs, particularly the Decoration API. I was wondering if it is possible to replace the appearance of the original text with decorative attachments (i.e. `ThemableDecorationAttachment`). Here's an example:

```
// from
foo('frequentlyAppearingUnwieldyLongString')

// to
foo(...)
```

In which the `...` are decoration attachments that hide the original text, while in the actual saved file it shows the full `'frequentlyAppearingUnwieldyLongString'`. Is that doable? Or can you only append decoration attachments without changing the original? I am not looking to modify the actual content of the document.

Comment: and what should happen if you want to edit this `LongString`, you can use a variable so it appears only once

Comment: @rioV8 On click it should expand the elipses and allow you to original content. There are ways that I can make the extension toggle-able.

Comment: can you use the folding mechanism and make a fold of 1 line and substitute the line with a line with ellipses inside

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The decoration API can only add decorations on top of the other output, not change it.

Comment: Do you know if there's other similar APIs that lets you visually replace text content?

Comment: Text is held in the editor model and the editor only shows what's in that model. A model can be assigned to multiple editors (showing so the same content in different windows), but not the other way around. You would have to manage your own model and sync changes between the original model and the one that is currently assigned.